# Is it possible to enumerate list of applications using box api?

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

Using Box api, is it possible to enumerate list of applications installed by an user? Ideally, I want to be able query permissions also.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @BorisSuvorov pretty much what I mentioned in the question. I've a business use case to enumerate list of install box applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it can't be done as of currently available APIs